# Failed to resolve: project :Library:materialDrawer

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to add **mikepenz's Material Drawer** as third party project. The reason I want to add it as project (not by just compile as dependency) so that I can modify the drawer's UI as per my requirement. But I cannot sync my gradle successfully and getting the following error:

> Failed to resolve:project :Library:materialDrawer

Here is my project structure:

```
-> root
  ->app
     ->Library
        -> materialDrawer
              -> app
              -> build.gradle
              -> settings.gradle
  -> build.gradle(project)
  -> settings.gradle
```

I tried to follow this project https://github.com/foragerr/android-multi-project-sample/blob/master/settings.gradle But in vein.

Here is my ***build.gradle(My project)*** file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.3.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

***settings.gradle*** (My project)

```
include ':app', ':Library:materialDrawer'
```

***build.gradle*** (app : My project)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.******"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 38
        versionName "2.1.8"

        generatedDensities = []

    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.equals("lint")) {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
/*
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.6.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
*/
    compile project(':Library:materialDrawer')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.github.ParkSangGwon:TedPermission:v1.0.12'
    compile 'hanks.xyz:smallbang-library:0.1.2'
    compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

***build.gradle*** (Project : materialDrawer)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.3.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

*My Android Studio is v2.3.3*. I'm scratching my head but couldn't find any solution. Please someone help me I'm stuck with this for three days...

Comment: @mikepenz Sir, can you help me into this?

Comment: you better use it as a dependency:

`compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.5@aar') {
 transitive = true
}`

Comment: @orvenito Yes, I've been doing like this all this time. But now I've to change the design of each drawerlayout. As there are limitations in modification, I would like to add mikepenz's library as module and edit xml files according to my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using:

```
compile project(':Library:materialDrawer')
```

gradle is looking for a `build.gradle` inside that module.
Checking your question, this file exists **but it is a top-level** file instead of a **module file**.

You should change structure in this way (you should not put the library folder inside another module)

```
-> root
  ->app
    -> build.gradle
  ->Library
      -> materialDrawer
           -> app
              -> build.gradle
           -> build.gradle
           -> settings.gradle
  -> build.gradle(project)
  -> settings.gradle
```

You have to change the `settings.gradle` with:

```
include ':app', ':materialDrawer'
project(':materialDrawer').projectDir = new File('/Library/materialDrawer/app')
```

Then as dependency use:

```
compile project(':materialDrawer')
```

Comment: @noob-Sci-Bot yes, but not put the library folder inside another module (app module)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Sir. The "Library" folder is placed at the root directory of my project, is it ok ?

Comment: @noob-Sci-Bot Yes. Of course you have to change the settings.gradle with the right folder.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error - **Error:(8, 0) Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':Library:materialDrawer:classpath' after it has been resolved.**

Comment: Sir, now getting another error - *Error:Dependency harriken-android:materialDrawer:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: D:\Workspace Android\harriken-android\Library\materialDrawer\app\build\outputs\apk\-v5.9.5-c595-release-unsigned.apk*

Comment: I solved the previous error. But now getting *No resource found  MaterialDrawerTheme* and 23 other errors regarding Style names

Comment: @noob-Sci-Bot this is some separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. There is something wrong with your style files. You may wish to consider asking a separate question

Comment: Yes, Sir. Thanks a lot for the precious help. Had been stuck for few days, really appreciate it.